# NiceMatrix first-row vertical alignment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, nicematrix

I have a NiceMatrix which is right aligned, but I am looking for a way to have the first-row centered.

Here is the code :

```
\begin{bNiceMatrix}[r,first-row,last-col,code-for-first-row = \scriptstyle \color{blue} \arabic{jCol},code-for-last-col = \scriptstyle \color{blue} \arabic{iRow}]
    &  &  &  & \\
    -2 & 3 & -4 & 5 & \\
    3 & -4 & 5 & -6 & \\
    -4 & 5 & -6 & 7 & \\
    5 & -6 & 7 & -8 & 
\end{bNiceMatrix}
```

And here is the result :

[image]

I would like to have the blue column numbers centered.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Z

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put each element of the ``first row'' in a mono-cell `\Block`. By default, the value of alignement of a `\Block` is `c` (centered).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

$\begin{bNiceMatrix}%
  [
    r,
    first-row,
    last-col,
    code-for-first-row = \Block{}{\color{blue} \scriptstyle \arabic{jCol}},
    code-for-last-col = \scriptstyle \color{blue} \arabic{iRow}
  ]
     &   &    &   & \\
  -2 & 3 & -4 & 5 & \\
  3 & -4 & 5 & -6 & \\
  -4 & 5 & -6 & 7 & \\
  5 & -6 & 7 & -8 & \\
\end{bNiceMatrix}$

\end{document}
```

As usual with `nicematrix`, you need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]